# Multirow details group in microsoft report tablix (SSRS or RDLC)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

Can I add second details row  in tablix ? Just detail row, because some column is too long and i want it to be placed just below basic detail row.In report designer I did not find such feature.
[image]

Comment: Just right-click on detail row (row header) and select to insert row - below and inside the group.